# Sometime the CDs are working when inserted to optical drive but not most of the time in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, cd

I had upgraded my system from 18.04 to 20.04 and since then I had never tried to run any CDs or DVDs but now I want to run the Audio and Video discs but **sometimes the CDs are available** via the sound juicer **but most of the times the disc are not available**.

I am using the MSI laptop and not using an external DVD writer.

Already tried the instruction from https://itsfoss.com/play-dvd-ubuntu-1310/

I had also cleaned the drive with tissue paper.

Please provide a solution as I need to take backup of some audio and video discs.

I tried to see if the optical drive is listed in discs under utilities but the optical drive is not listed.
My optical drive is available at the boot time to the system.

Note the following commands are ran by running a live Ubuntu system using the USB.

output of the command **sudo lshw**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw 
ubuntu                      
    description: Notebook
    product: GL62 7QF (16J5.3)
    vendor: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
    version: REV:1.0
    serial: 9S716J5621657ZH1000032
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0.0 dmi-3.0.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=GL sku=16J5.3 uuid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-4CCC6ADC170D
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: MS-16J5
       vendor: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       version: REV:1.0
       serial: BSS-0123456789
       slot: Default string
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 1
          version: E16J5IMS.305
          date: 12/15/2016
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 6MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 3e
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: HMA41GS6AFR8N-TF
             vendor: SK Hynix
             physical id: 0
             serial: B0827047
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 42
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 43
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 44
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 6MiB
          capacity: 6MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 45
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 3498MHz
          capacity: 4005MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 05
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:de000000-df0fffff ioport:c0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: 3D controller
                product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a2
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:127 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: HD Graphics 630
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:128 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:126 memory:df310000-df31ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-43-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Mass storage device
                   product: Cruzer Force
                   vendor: SanDisk
                   physical id: 8
                   bus info: usb@1:8
                   version: 1.27
                   serial: 4C530009640425105121
                   capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi
                   configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: a
                   bus info: usb@1:a
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Video
                   product: BisonCam, NB Pro
                   vendor: Bison
                   physical id: b
                   bus info: usb@1:b
                   version: 3.04
                   serial: 200901010001
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:3
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: USB2.0-CRW
                   vendor: Generic
                   physical id: c
                   bus info: usb@1:c
                   version: 39.60
                   serial: 20100201396000000
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=rtsx_usb maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-43-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:df32e000-df32efff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:129 memory:df32d000-df32dfff
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:125 memory:df328000-df329fff memory:df32c000-df32c0ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:df32b000-df32b7ff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 memory:df200000-df2fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: 10
                serial: 30:e3:7a:ec:f8:d3
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-43-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 3168-29.ucode ip=192.168.0.147 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:131 memory:df200000-df201fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:df100000-df1fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: enp3s0
                version: 10
                serial: 4c:cc:6a:dc:17:0d
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=5.8.0-43-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                resources: irq:19 memory:df100000-df13ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:df324000-df327fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: CM238 HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:130 memory:df320000-df323fff memory:df300000-df30ffff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:df32a000-df32a0ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device MSI0007
          physical id: 0
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device SYN1507
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 aux
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:08
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 9
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:09
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: a
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: b
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             capabilities: audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: status=open
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: c
          logical name: scsi3
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: HGST HTS721010A9
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: A3U0
             serial: JR100XD333EYGE
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=acfe92f2
           *-volume
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: 1.0
                serial: a81b46e7-7661-47b5-aab2-5b6e8047571c
                size: 931GiB
                capacity: 931GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2020-05-03 08:47:39 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2021-05-23 11:35:54 mounted=2021-05-23 11:36:01 state=clean
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: d
          logical name: scsi4
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: Cruzer Force
             vendor: SanDisk
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: 1.27
             serial: 4C530009640425105121
             size: 14GiB (16GB)
             capabilities: removable
             configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/sdb
                size: 14GiB (16GB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: signature=38b1c112
              *-volume:0
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: mkfs.fat
                   physical id: 2
                   logical name: /dev/sdb2
                   version: FAT12
                   serial: 54c5-9c6c
                   size: 15EiB
                   capabilities: primary boot fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
              *-volume:1
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 3
                   logical name: /dev/sdb3
                   logical name: /var/log
                   logical name: /var/crash
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 26342f3c-be06-4bfb-a6ec-babcea15e24c
                   size: 12GiB
                   capacity: 12GiB
                   capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2021-05-23 12:48:06 filesystem=ext4 label=writable lastmountpoint=/root/var/crash modified=2021-05-23 12:48:26 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2021-05-23 12:48:26 state=mounted
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       physical id: 1
       version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       capacity: 32768mWh
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

lets see the output of sudo lshw -C disk

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C disk
  *-cdrom                   
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       capabilities: audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: status=open
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: HGST HTS721010A9
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: A3U0
       serial: JR100XD333EYGE
       size: 931GiB (1TB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=acfe92f2
  *-disk
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: Cruzer Force
       vendor: SanDisk
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: 1.27
       serial: 4C530009640425105121
       size: 14GiB (16GB)
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sdb
          size: 14GiB (16GB)
          capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuration: signature=38b1c112
```

output of sudo mount

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=3967004k,nr_inodes=991751,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=803452k,mode=755)
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/cow on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/cow/upper,workdir=/cow/work)
/dev/sdb3 on /var/log type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdb3 on /var/crash type ext4 (rw,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=18664)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-34-1804_66.snap on /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1988.snap on /snap/core18/1988 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_11036.snap on /snap/snapd/11036 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1514.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_518.snap on /snap/snap-store/518 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
tmpfs on /run/user/999 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=803448k,mode=700,uid=999,gid=999)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=999,group_id=999)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=803452k,mode=755)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/snap-store.mnt type nsfs (rw)
/dev/fuse on /run/user/999/doc type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=999,group_id=999)
```

Please also look for the output of the command run on my ubuntu installation

```
sachin@sachin:~$ sudo lshw -C disk
[sudo] password for sachin: 
  *-disk                    
       description: ATA Disk
       product: HGST HTS721010A9
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: A3U0
       serial: JR100XD333EYGE
       size: 931GiB (1TB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=acfe92f2
```

Should I raise a bug in the Ubunut forum?

Comment: It's it possible the discs that work are all one type? There are different lasers for different tech, eg CDRW vs commercial CD-A/CDROM. Might be a part broken drive.

Comment: Actually, I had tried with more than 5 CDs and also I Just want to read and My laptop has DVD writer

Comment: It sounds like a loose wire or something, nothing to do with Ubuntu. To test, boot from an installation USB and use the try Ubuntu option. Then try reading your CDs. If it falls then it is a hardware problem.

Comment: ` configuration: status=open` looks like it thinks tray is open

Comment: @Lol4t0 the tray was not open but it contains the disk but not able to mount.

Comment: I understand, but your system thinks it's open. You can try `eject -T`

Comment: @Lol4t0 the configuration you are referring is when i was checking with a live disk but without that my optical drive is not available